# Closed as Primarily Opinion based

Tags: discussion

I just want to understand the specific close reason for this question:
[Why http + ssh is not popular?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23993)

While I understand the question text seeming opinion based, "*why has it not been as popular...*", I would like to think the answers are more factual and 'best practice' based.

If the question was "what is your favorite security protocol", then I would interpret that as completely opinion based.

But if someone asked, say "Why isn't Frame-Relay as popular as a WAN technology", that there would be some definitive, factual answers which describe its decrease in popularity in comparison to other WAN technologies.

I guess my root question is, what parts of the question made it seem primarily opinion based?

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for another moderator's thought process so I won't try to answer why another moderator thought it was opinion based.

Looking at that question myself, I would have closed it as being off-topic. It is really about applications and how applications interact and really has nothing to do with networking. While the reason is different, the end result is the same.

Now, I do agree it is an interesting question. However as a community we have discussed and decided on topics that are on-topic on this site, and "interesting" isn't one of the categories because interesting is subjective.

As things stand, this just isn't the right place for that question.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @YLearn. It's an interesting question, and it would be a good *discussion* (Network Engineering is clearly not a discussion site), elsewhere (such as chat), but this is dealing with the layers above what the community has defined for Network Engineering.

The answer to other, example question you pose, "Why isn't Frame-Relay as popular as a WAN technology?" is also rather subjective if you don't work for a carrier. The carriers quit offering frame relay (as layer-1) for a variety of reasons, although most still offer frame relay (as layer-2) over point-to-point TDM circuits. (In a few years, we could be asking why TDM went away.) I'm not sure that the answers to that question could be fact-based enough for Network Engineering, but could also be discussed in chat.

Comment: Yes! Ask in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/)! Perfect topic for chat.